# How can I get rid of the message that comes at the beginning of my amp-story when visited for the first time?

Tags: amp-html, amp-story

I have made an amp-story which, when visited for the first time asks for "You must enable the amp-story experiment to view this content".

This is the link to the story: https://www.krenovate.com/amp/campaign/pets-completed.html

How can I get rid of that prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is seen when using version 0.1 of amp-story.  You can resolve this by using version 1.0.  The version is dependent on the URL of the amp-story script you include in your document.  For 1.0, you want:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-story" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-story-1.0.js"></script>
```